# Python Time SeriesSplit

Tags: time-series

I have the following question:

I have a timer series. I have done my preprocessing, and now I have x, which contains multiple features and y, which contains my output. I have split it into the train, test: `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`

I now want to do a regression and a gridsearch.

Since I have a time series, I cant do the k-fold cross-validation. So  I wanted to use the `TimeSeriesSplit`.

But what exactly am I splitting? I thought I would split the training set into train and test/validate to train my model, validate/select my hyperparameter and then forecast using the test. Is this correct?
And how do I choose `n_splits`?

I have now the following code:

```py
pipe=Pipeline....
pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

tss=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
for train_index, test_index in tss(train):
print('train:', train_index, 'test:', test_index

clf=GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=tss)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to sklearn documentation:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html

"Provides train/test indices to split time series data samples that are observed at fixed time intervals, in train/test sets. In each split, test indices must be higher than before, and thus shuffling in cross validator is inappropriate."

The way to go, if you want to validate a time series model is **nested cross validation** some info about it is in the link bellow:

https://mlfromscratch.com/nested-cross-validation-python-code/

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I am not 100% sure if I am corret: For nested cross validation I would still split my train series in train and validation and tune my parameters on validation, forecast on test set and compare the forecast to tune my parameters in the grid search, right?

Comment: No problem. You will tune your parameters in training set, use a metric of validation in validation set, select one or some models and test them, with the same metric of validation. The is no "right and only way" of do this. Depending on the problem you can make it different and still being right. It just must make sense.